# Intellij shows characters of indent on paste a string

Tags: intellij-idea

So I just do paste string and it happens:

```
static final String XML_STRING= "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n" +
        "<SomeRequest xmlns=\"http://some.place.com/scheme.xsd\">\n" +
        "\t<TransactionDetails>\n" +
        "\t\t<messageId>578309573490573</messageId>\n" +
        "\t\t<dateTimeStamp>2001-10-26T21:32:52Z</dateTimeStamp>\n" +
        "\t\t<orderId>7878787878</orderId>\n" +
        ........
```

how can I hide the ***\t*** characters?

Comment: Can you try this once  `Settings | Editor | General | Smart Keys –> smart indent pasted lines --> uncheck`.

Comment: @AjayKrChoudhary thanks, but it doesn't help

Comment: Ah, Ok. I have tried checking multiple settings related to this. For instance, `Settings/Preferences | Editor | General | Smart Keys --> Reformat on Paste` and trying every option. Not sure even toggling this will solve your problem.

Comment: Yes, before I wrote this question I had tried some options too, but unsuccessfully.

Comment: Do you have any custom plugins installed?

Comment: @y.bedrov What do you mean "custom"? I have for example Sonar, JProfiler, Docker, etc. Not something special.

Comment: I meant non-bundled plugins. Could you please try to disable all plugins mentioned in "Downloaded" section in "Settings/Preferences | Plugins - Installed"?

Comment: I did it, doesn't help. Maybe this behavior is proper? I previously paste the xml string to the Editor app (TextMate) and do Indent Selection for formatting, probably TextMate inserts \t characters. Should the Intellij editor show them or not?

Comment: Could you please share the source file, so I could check paste on my side?